# Django Rest Framework Reverse() Method Fails

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

My main urls.py is located here ahlami -> ahlami -> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/accounts/', include('accounts.api.urls')),
]
```

My accounts app urls.py is located here ahlami -> accounts -> api -> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserView.as_view(), name='user-detail')
]
```

One of my accounts views.py returns

```
token = Token.objects.create(......)
return Response(data=AnonymousUserTokenResponseSerializer(instance=token).data)
```

My token model has three fields only. For simplicity, I listed one field below

```
class Token(rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

AnonymousUserTokenResponseSerializer is linked to the Token model and returns three json attributes

```
class AnonymousUserTokenResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')
    user_url = reverse(viewname='user-detail')
    class Meta:
        model = Token
        fields = ('key',
                  'user_id',
                  'user_url')
```

AnonymousUserTokenResponseSerializer fails because it can't identify reverse()

```
user_url = reverse(viewname='user-detail')
```

**python manage.py runserver** throws the error below because of the line above

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
> 'ahlami.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see
> valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
> circular import.

My settings is located here ahlami -> ahlami -> settings -> base.py and base.py has this

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'ahlami.urls'
```

I expect to get an output that looks like but couldn't because of the error above.

```
{
    "key": "891e388399f2fcae016fe6887107034239041478",
    "user_id": 29,
    "user_url": http://localhost/api/accounts/users/29 
}
```

How can I resolve this error and make reverse() work?

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
> 'ahlami.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see
> valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
> circular import.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that you have put `user_url` in the serializer since it is not a ***serializer field***

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean user_url is not part Token? user_id is not part of the serializer either. I declared user_id and it worked.

Comment: `user_id` is a *DRF Serializer field*, but `user_url` is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield)

```
class AnonymousUserTokenResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')
    user_url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='user-detail',
        source='user.id',
        lookup_field='pk'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Token
        fields = ('key', 'user_id', 'user_url')
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Thanks Arakkal... I had to do few changes. I had to pass context in my serializer's method `return Response(data=AnonymousUserTokenResponseSerializer(instance=token, context={'request': request}).data)` and I had to change to  serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField to serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField `user_url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='user-detail',
        source='user.id',
        lookup_field='pk',
        read_only='True'
    )`

Comment: Just trying to understand why I had to pass return context={'request': request}. If you have any thoughts, feel free to share it here. Anyway, I'll google it.

Comment: coz, DRF uses the request object internally to build the URL